# Cleanly finish Python 3.6 application at shutdown on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, shutdown

I would like to know how to "cleanly" finish the execution of a python application on Windows shutdown.
My application starts at startup, opens a text file and keeps running while Windows is on, What I want to do is to, somehow, capture the shutdown signal and inmediately stop the processes running and close the text file with the **io** method `myFile.close()`, finishing the program by itself, and not forced by Windows. Any idea about how that could be done?
Thank you in advance.
Regards